# How to correctly iterate all records of a multi-level depth structure in Rust?

Tags: struct, iterator, rust

I would like to know how to iterate correctly in Rust all results contained in a data structure arranged like this:

```
struct Node {
    id: i64,
    nodes: Vec<Node>
}
```

Where the records inserted in this structure have several levels of depth. Something like:

```
{id: 1, nodes: [
    {id: 2, nodes: [ 
        {id: 3, nodes: []}, 
        {id: 4, nodes: []},
        {id: 5, nodes: [
            {id: 6, nodes: []},
            {id: 7, nodes: [
                {id: 8, nodes: []},
                {id: 9, nodes: []}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]};
```

Comment: You haven't shown *any* attempt at solving your own problem. Stack Overflow isn't a service where people write code for you; it is expected that you show some research or effort.

Comment: But I do not know much about Rust, sir. That's why I'm asking for some help.

The basic way I know to iterate would be to use .iter(), but it does not deepen the levels in the structure. I would have to do a recursive function, but the type treatment got complicated for me now.

Comment: And I did not ask to create code for myself. I just asked what would be the best way to iterate through multi-levels. The person might well respond only to something like "use this syscall X, or structure in a Y-way, or do it recursively using Z or W". Or just pointing some documentation or example in the internet.

Comment: You haven't even described what "correct" means. You may need to read up on [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: "correct" based on language best pratices; and now, with this links, you help me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple recursive function to handle the problem and everything is fine now. I do not know what was my mistake yesterday when I created this topic. The real problem is little different from what I asked for, but the essence is the same:

```
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Node {
    id: i64,
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    focused: bool,
}

struct Controller {
    focused: i32,
}

impl Controller {
    fn get_focused(&mut self) -> i32 {
        let nodes: Node = ....; // code skipped. represented with JSON object above, but with 'focused' member

        for node in nodes.iter() {
            self.focused = self.node_iterator(node);
        }
        self.focused
    }

    fn node_iterator(&self, node: Node) -> i32 {
        let mut focused: i32 = 0;

        if node.nodes.len() > 0 {
            for n in node.nodes.iter() {
                if n.nodes.len() > 0 {
                    focused = self.node_iterator(n);
                    if focused > 0 {
                        return focused;
                    }
                } else {
                    if n.focused == true {
                        focused = n.id as i32;
                        return focused;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut controller = Controller { focused: 0 };

    controller.get_focused();

    println!("{}", controller.focused);
}
```

Comment: Incredible! This is what I call 'correct' :) Thanks for the effort. Now my mission is to understand piece by piece.